# Why not all my files are copied in the app bundle when new script is added?

Tags: xcode

I added a new script to execute in the Build Phases.

The goal of that script is depending of a "define" variable, I want to copy a file in `/Users/<user>/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/<app_name>/Build/Products/<scheme_name>-iphoneos/myapp.app` file.

For some reason, when that script is present, it does what it needs to do, but some files are not included in my_app.app file anymore!?! For example, the size of that .app file is supposed to me 114MB, but with the script included, it goes down to 108MB!

I tried to move the order of the execution of that script without success.

Here is the script with my 3 ways (did not do all those at once)

```
# Merge banner and text
if [ $VERSION_ALPHA -eq 1 ]
then

    # First try
    cp "${SRCROOT}/${PROJECT_NAME}/myfile" "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${PRODUCT_NAME}.app/"
    
    # Second try
    cp "${SRCROOT}/${PROJECT_NAME}/myfile" "${CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/${UNLOCALIZED_RESOURCES_FOLDER_PATH}/"

    # Third try
    rsync -ua "${SRCROOT}/${PROJECT_NAME}/myfile" "${CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/${UNLOCALIZED_RESOURCES_FOLDER_PATH}/"

elif [ $VERSION_DEV -eq 1 ]
then
    ....
fi
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting over with the second line worked. I still don't know why, but it is working